# Splitting a string of multiple bracketed values to a list of bracketed values in Python

Tags: python, arrays, regex, python-re

I would like to create a list of strings inside of brackets, given one long string of multiple bracketed values.

For instance, my string looks like this:

```
initial_string = '(1.5 0.1 0.3) (1.1 0.3 0.2) (1.9 0.6 0.4) (1.7 0.1 0.2)'
```

I would like it to become:

```
['(1.5 0.1 0.3)', '(1.1 0.3 0.2)', '(1.9 0.6 0.4)', '(1.7 0.1 0.2)']
```

I tried a few things, like re.split(' ', initial_string) but that splits the values inside the string as well.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Using lookarounds to check for the parentheses:

```
import re

re.split(r'(?<=\))\s+(?=\()', initial_string)
```

Output:

```
['(1.5 0.1 0.3)', '(1.1 0.3 0.2)', '(1.9 0.6 0.4)', '(1.7 0.1 0.2)']
```

Regex:

```
(?<=\)) # match (but do not consume) a ")"
\s+     # match spaces
(?=\()  # match (but do not consume) a "("
```

Answer (score 2):

I would keep it simple and just use `re.findall` here:

```py
initial_string = '(1.5 0.1 0.3) (1.1 0.3 0.2) (1.9 0.6 0.4) (1.7 0.1 0.2)'
matches = re.findall(r'\(.*?\)', initial_string)
print(matches)
# ['(1.5 0.1 0.3)', '(1.1 0.3 0.2)', '(1.9 0.6 0.4)', '(1.7 0.1 0.2)']
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use the `.split()` function and split on the space character

i.e

```py
initial_string = '(1.5 0.1 0.3) (1.1 0.3 0.2) (1.9 0.6 0.4) (1.7 0.1 0.2)'
print(initial_string.split(' '))
```

This outputs

`['(1.5', '0.1', '0.3)', '(1.1', '0.3', '0.2)', '(1.9', '0.6', '0.4)', '(1.7', '0.1', '0.2)']`